# Riddle: Beyond the greatest tower

Tags: riddle

> It is I all should thank
>   who gives you so much power
>
> In the age of the ankh
>   I was loved by the sower
>
> High up the firmament
>   beyond the greatest tower
>
> Be it any instant
>   half a world I devour

Probably a little easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Answer**

> The sun

It is I all should thank
who gives you so much power

> No life without the sun's energy (= power)

In the age of the ankh
I was loved by the sower

> The Egyptian sun god Ra. The ankh was an important symbol in that era.

High up the firmament
beyond the greatest tower

> The sun is high in the sky, way beyond mortal reach.

Be it any instant
half a world I devour

> One half of Earth has the sun (day), the other does not (night)

Comment: +1, although (1) this has the same *answer* as the first answer (but yours provides explanations and the other doesn't) and (2) IMHO, you could do better with the "sower" clue.

Comment: Thanks! I reply without checking any other answers as to not get influenced :).

Answer (score 4):

New answer

> The sun!

Old answer

> Shade or a Shadow?  Line 2 - Loved by Egyptian farmers (because it's flipping hot there), Line 3 - a shadow cast by a tower, Line 4 - nighttime

Comment: Maybe seperate this post into 2 seperate answers. though i think you 2nd (new) answer is correct ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is, going by all you have given me:

> rain

Comment: Can you please how your answer fits the puzzle ? answer without explanation are usually deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Are you:

> Nutritions/Food?

It is I all should thank
who gives you so much power

> Food gives us strength.

In the age of the ankh
I was loved by the sower

> The sower were always hunger and happy to get food.

High up the firmament
beyond the greatest tower

> Food used to be locked up (such as grain) in huge towers by the wealthy.

Be it any instant
half a world I devour

> Half the world is in hunger, so without the food they devour.

Comment: One catch, food being locked by in towers doesn't make then *beyond* the towers